# docker-machine can't SSH into AWSEC2 instance after instance's IP change

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I restarted my EC2 instance (w/ a particular IP), which changed it's IP address.

Now, when I attempt to `docker-machine ssh [instance]`, I receive `exit status 255`. If I `docker-machine ls`, I see `Unable to query docker version: Get https://[new ip]/v1.15/version: x509: certificate is valid for [old ip], not [new ip]`.

I've tried `docker-machine regenerate-certs [instance]` and it gets stuck on "Waiting for SSH to be available..."

I've also tried:
`docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs [instance]` w/ the same results.

Is my EC2 instance lost to me now?

Comment: i have few questions ?
1) are you able to see youe ec2 inside your account in that particular region? if yes then why dont you try to connect using ec2 browser instance connect?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yeah, I can see it. The problem w/ EC2 Browser Instance Connect is that it requires a user w/ a password—and I can't set a password for my user w.o. having access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [assign an Elastic IP to your EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-associate-static-public-ip/) instance as elastic IPs don't change when your instance is restarted.

However, do keep in mind that elastic IPs are not a scalable solution in most cases as AWS provides only 5 elastic IPs per account per region by default.

Comment: Well, first I'd need this to be scalable—but second the ability to assign an elastic IP address doesn't actually solve my problem at all. The instance would still have a different IP address than that which was originally assigned to it.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Elastic IPs are public IPs that are permanently attached to your EC2 instances as long as you want, I suggest that you read this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/intro-elastic-ip-addresses/. As for the scalability problem, I do not have enough information about your system to comment :)

Comment: I know what elastic IPs are—but that doesn't solve the problem that I'm experiencing *right now*. That is a good solution for the future, when I regain access to my EC2 instance, but the issue is that I can't connect to the EC2 instance *regardless* of what the IP is